# How to get remote desktop by ssh directly into a disconnected Docker container? IE, not using X of Host, but VNC or X2Go inside container

Tags: docker, ssh, x11, vnc-viewer

We would like to provide a container for use by people who don't have a login on the Host.  But we would like them to be able to use X2Go so that they get a desktop.  This is possible with a VM, of course, but can it also be done with Docker?

We have the container running in disconnected mode.  We also have port forwarding set up, so that there's a separate port on the Host that is used to ssh directly into the container (without first ssh into Host).

We can ssh just fine, but when trying a graphical remote login tool such as VNC or X2Go, it refuses to connect.  So, we tried installing X Windows into the container, but when we try to start X Server, it says there is no TTY (IE, there's no display device to connect to).

Ideas how to get past this block?

Thanks

Comment: A multi-user multi-process system with an ssh daemon, display server, _etc._ doesn't really sound like something you'd generally run in a Docker container.  It's _possible_ but you'd be reinventing a lot of the machinery that you'd get for free running an off-the-shelf Linux distribution in a VM.

Comment: Thanks.  We're looking for the efficiency advantages of container -- VM owns cores and DRAM -- container shares, only using cores as needed, and only owning DRAM actually used.